# How to output a sound over the 3.5 mm jack of the Raspberry Pi using Python?

Tags: python, pi-2, audio

I just want to:

**play a simple 440 Hz sound** [no solutions about playing files]

- **using the 3.5 mm jack** [no GPIO solutions] pluged loudspeaker **of the raspberry pi**
- using a **python script** without any additional library that i have to download.

Can somebody give me a sample code?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57302/discussion-on-question-by-doej1367-how-to-output-a-sound-over-the-3-5-mm-jack-of).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one method to generate sound on the jack, and that is to use the GPIO either directly or via playing sound.

As you have ruled out using the GPIO there is no positive answer to your question.

Comment: as i still found no answer i assume you are right. I'll play mp3 files created with "audacity". thx for your answer anyway. ;-)